# Turbo C++ erroneously executes loop with literal 0 in condition

Tags: c, turbo-c++

I wrote 0 in the condition of `for` loop so it was once executed and when I wrote j instead of 0 and j was initialized to 0 then the for loop was not executed even once. What is the reason behind it?

```
for(i=0;0;i++)
```

and

```
j = 0;
for(i=0;j;i++)
```

the first one executed once but the next one did not execute.

#### EDIT:

This is a bug in Turbo C++ compiler.

Comment: Neither of those loops should execute.

Comment: [I'm quite sure that both are not executed.](http://ideone.com/jwFbeN) What's your compiler?

Comment: You should post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Turbo c++ compiler

Comment: We need to see a _complete program that we can compile and run for ourselves_, containing this loop that you say is executed once.

Comment: Also, please tell us the exact version number of the Turbo C++ compiler you are using.  Turbo C++ is very old and it's _possible_, although unlikely, that it is generating incorrect code.

Comment: Its a turbo c++ 3.2 version which i am using.

Comment: Well....don't you think it's time to update your development platform? It is veeeeeeery cheap ;)

Comment: You should enter the fact that this is a bug as an answer, and preferably provide the version number and complete source code and compiler settings to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## This is a bug in the Turbo c++

Version : 3.2.2.0

Following issue is reported on **[Github as an Issue](https://github.com/vineetchoudhary/TurboCPP/issues/1#issue-395882012)**:

---

Following gif will provide the error explaination.
[gif of execution of the above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4NGb.gif)

### Code for regeneration

```
void main()
{
   int i,j=0;
   clrscr();
   for(i = 0; 0 ; i++) // you could try replacing 0 with variable j
      printf("\nHello");
   getch();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic C question that you should be able to answer yourself.  The second parameter in the `for` construct is a conditional.  If it evaluates to true, the loop continues.  If it evaluates to false, the loop halts.

When you set the second parameter to the literal `0` or to a variable, `j`, which is set to zero, you are setting it to a value that evaluates to a logical false.

Comment: That is what the code does, but OP is telling us that the first one (with literal) is execute.

Comment: I suspect he's just not communicating clearly because, as you obviously know, that can't happen. :)

Comment: But the for loop  with a literal 0 is executed in a turbo compiler and is not executed in code blocks compiler. Thank you

Comment: If that is true, then there is something broken about the turbo compiler.  How old is that thing?  20 years?

Comment: Yes, more than 20 years.